# I am learning SQL and work for a school system

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My quest is this to get only one line per EmploymentAssignment row even if the staff member has multiple rows in the Employment table. I am to (Include fields from the existing staffMember view that come from Person, Identity, EmploymentAssignment, School and Department.  Include a new field with the alias "districtStart" reporting the person's earliest Employment.startDate.) This is a question from my exam and I can not figure out how to make it only pull one assignment. This is what I have and she says it is correct but... it is pulling more than one assignment. Any help would keep me from banging my head against a wall anymore.

```
SELECT
     p.personID,
     p.stateID,
     p.staffNumber,
     p.staffStateID,
     i.identityID,
     i.effectiveDate,
     i.lastName,
     i.firstName,
     i.middleName,
     i.suffix,
     i.alias,
     i.gender,
     i.birthdate,
     i.ssn,
     i.raceEthnicity,
     ea.assignmentID,
     ea.startDate,
     MIN(e.startdate) AS DistrictStart,
     ea.endDate,
     ea.title,
     ea.type,
     ea.teache,
     ea.specialEd,
     ea.behavior,
     ea.health,
     ea.advisor,
     ea.supervisor,
     ea.foodservice,
     ea.departmentID,
     s.schoolID,
     s.name   schoolName,
     s.number schoolNumber,
     d.name   departmentName,
     ea.excludeReferral,
     ea.counselor
FROM     dbo.Person p WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN dbo.[Identity] i WITH (NOLOCK)
     ON       p.currentIdentityID = i.identityID
     INNER JOIN dbo.Employment e
     ON       e.personID = p.personID
     INNER JOIN dbo.EmploymentAssignment ea WITH (NOLOCK)
     ON       p.personID = ea.personID
     INNER JOIN dbo.School s WITH (NOLOCK)
     ON       s.schoolID = ea.schoolID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Department d WITH (NOLOCK)
     ON       d.departmentID = ea.departmentID
GROUP BY e.startdate,
     p.personID,
     p.stateID,
     p.staffNumber,
     p.staffStateID,
     i.identityID,
     i.effectiveDate,
     i.lastName,
     i.firstName,
     i.middleName,
     i.suffix,
     i.alias,
     i.gender,
     i.birthdate,
     i.ssn,
     i.raceEthnicity,
     ea.assignmentID,
     ea.startDate,
     ea.endDate,
     ea.title,
     ea.type,
     ea.teacher,
     ea.specialEd,
     ea.behavior,
     ea.health,
     ea.advisor,
     ea.supervisor,
     ea.foodservice,
     ea.departmentID,
     s.schoolID,
     s.name,
     s.number,
     d.name,
     ea.excludeReferral,
     ea.counselor
```

Comment: Ouch! You've copied that out of Access haven't you?  Perhaps you should try asking your question with correct punctuation and capital letters.

Comment: more likely SQL server. Access would have put the joins in multiple levels of nested `()` pairs, put `[]` around all the field names and otherwise made it even less readable.

Comment: Seems to be TSQL. Which SQL variant is this?

Comment: www.sqlinform.com is your friend

Comment: @Manos Dilaverakis  and now its my friend too

Comment: Witch EmploymentAssignment do you want first, last, endDate is null?

Comment: @Manos - Or http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm if you go over their 100 line limit.

Comment: @ Conrad ..This is the question as she posted it exactly ? Write a query to substitute for the staffMember view, ensuring there will be only one line per EmploymentAssignment row even if the staff member has multiple rows in the Employment table. (Include fields from the existing staffMember view that come from Person, Identity, EmploymentAssignment, School and Department.  Include a new field with the alias "districtStart" reporting the person's earliest Employment.startDate.)

Comment: @Lesa hmm still not clear to me. Perhaps you should include some sample output as it is and what it is you want

Comment: @ Conrad This is her reply to me..

Comment: When I run this I get 6 rows for Gordon ** who has 3 assignments.

Comment: @Matt yes it appears to be repeating the rows twice he has 3 assignments and they are repeating twice

Comment: my assumption is that the earliest date they seek is found in the assignment table because that would repeat numerous times... but i could be wrong . Regarding your initail question wrap that in a derieved table and use top to restrict it to one row ... good luck

Comment: @Andrew That sounds like just what I need I wish I knew enough to do it. I am trying and having no luck?

Comment: use this // (select top 1 * FROM EmploymentAssignment ea WHERE p.personID = ea.personID )ea // replace this //dbo.EmploymentAssignment ea WITH (NOLOCK)

Answer (score 1):

You need to take out e.startdate from your group by statement.  In your query you are taking MIN(e.startdate), but this won't do anything if you are also grouping by it.  Here is a trivial example to show you what I mean:

```
select '20110101' as StartDate
into #DatesExample
union select '20110102' as StartDate
union select '20110103' as StartDate

select min(StartDate)
from #DatesExample
group by StartDate

select min(StartDate)
from #DatesExample
```